# Tuple into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, api, tuples

I'm trying to make data pulled from an api into a dataframe.

```
api = OpenSkyApi()

#bbox = (min latitude, max latitude, min longitude, max longitude)
states = api.get_states(bbox=(38.793968, 39.002143, -77.170372, -76.868058))
for s in states.states:
    x=((s.longitude, s.latitude, s.baro_altitude, s.velocity, s.callsign ))
```

My result is this: `(-77.0419, 38.8545, None, 0, 'AAL2140 ')`

I'm trying to make the result into a pandas dataframe where the columns would be "Long", "Lat", "Alt", "Vel", "Call"

I tried doing `df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns =['Long'])`  But that makes my tuple into one column.

Honestly, I'm new at this and I'm sure something could change in the `x=((s.longitude, s.latitude, s.baro_altitude, s.velocity, s.callsign ))` part but I'm not sure.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: have you tried like df = pd.DataFrame([x], columns =["Long", "Lat", "Alt", "Vel", "Call"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store all the tuples in a list.  Then you can create a dataframe that uses the list as the data source, and specify the columns.

```
api = OpenSkyApi()

#initiate empty list
state_tuples = []

#bbox = (min latitude, max latitude, min longitude, max longitude)
states = api.get_states(bbox=(38.793968, 39.002143, -77.170372, -76.868058))
for s in states.states:
    x=((s.longitude, s.latitude, s.baro_altitude, s.velocity, s.callsign ))
    
    #pop on
    state_tuples.append(x)


df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['long', 'lat', 'alt', 'vel', 'callsign'])
```

Comment: Perfect! I took out the 4"()" s.longitude, s.latitude, s.baro_altitude, s.velocity, s.callsign and it worked thank you~